# I have a circuit with a 9V battery, followed by 3 10 ohm resistors, and an led all in series...?

Tags: led, batteries, resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbL0fA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a circuit with a 9V battery, followed by 3 10 ohm resistors, and an led all in series. The led has a forward voltage of 2.5V and .5A. I am a little confused, however, as the optimal resistance for this led would be 21 ohms correct? How does this change when I use 30 ohms instead? Does it lower the current??

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE please use the tool and draw a circuit when possible. Its also a good idea to check out the help center (if you haven't) and review the guidelines on asking and answering questions.

Comment: You may not get half an amp out of a traditional 9v "transistor" battery (or at least not for long) though exotic versions or a pack of larger cells might have sufficiently low internal loss to push that.

Answer (score 1):

The diode has a I-V curve (at [analog.com](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/eps/diode-curves)) [image]
This means that the more voltage you put across it the more current it draws, you put the resistors in series to limit the current if the voltage rail is too high. If you have 5 volts it would burn out most LED's if you had a 2.5V supply you wouldn't need the resistors. When you say optimal resistance, the current limiting resistance is totally up to you. However too much current and you will burn up the LED, too little and it wont light up.

Answer (score 0):

**30 \$\Omega\$**

If you have a multimeter it would be very instructive to take a couple of measurements and calculate the current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foVaBR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Circuit and measurement points.*

- Measure the voltage across the LED (VM2). Let's assume you read 2.5 V.
- Measure the voltage across the resistors (VM1). Let's assume that the battery is good so you should get 6.5 V. (We'll call it '6' to simplify the maths.)
- Measure the battery voltage. It should be the sum of the first two readings.

Next work out the current through the resistors from Ohm's Law. \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {6}{30} = 0.2~A \$. (You can improve the accuracy of this calculation by using the measured voltage and resistance values.)

Confirm the calculation by taking a current measurement as shown by AM1.

**20 \$\Omega\$**

Now work out what will happen if we decrease the resistance to 20 \$\Omega\$. The LED voltage will be reasonably constant over a wide range of currents (unlike the resistor whose voltage drop will be directly proportional to the current). The current will go up. By how much? Is it safe to test it?